# Is it possible to use NodeJS modules like "oauth" in my Firefox Addon?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firefox, oauth, firefox-addon

This is the first time I'm writing a Firefox addon. For the addon I'm trying to write, I need to make calls to [Twitter's APIs](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public). In order to do so, I need an oauth library to start off.

I discovered that there [already exists such a library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/oauth) in the npm package repository. Seeing how Firefox addons are written in Javascript, I decided to try using it. Unfortunately, it seems that I cannot simply use modules from NodeJS by running `npm install oauth`.

```
Message: Module `crypto` is not found at resource://gre/modules/commonjs/crypto.js
```

However, is there some other way that I can use these modules, considering it is nonetheless written in Javascript? I am hoping to not have to write an oauth library from scratch just to start my addon.

To clarify, I'm writing addon code, not content script. I want the addon to be the one making the calls to Twitter API.

The code I currently have is pretty simple. I have a class `twitter.js`:

```
var OAuth = require("oauth");
var OAuth2 = OAuth.OAuth2;

var Twitter = function() {

};

module.exports = Twitter;
```

And in my `index.js` I simply add some code to:

```
var Twitter = require("./twitter");
var twitter = new Twitter();
```

Comment: If you have a githb repository I can help you with a PR to set up this twitter oauth. I know people struggle a lot with this kind of stuff.

Comment: Did you see my solution i posted below? It is a copy paste solution for Twitter.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the module, but it often is possible. The [Browserify](http://browserify.org/) makes it easy to convert node modules for use in the browser.

Comment: Maybe I am confusing the purpose of Browserify, but I now have the following error: `TypeError: global.XMLHttpRequest is not a constructor`. To clarify, I'm writing addon code, not content script. I want the addon to be the one making the calls to Twitter API. Am I using Browserify wrong?

Comment: Browserify implements the node API, so you can use node modules in browser environments. I'm not that familiar with what limitation are placed on Firefox Addons. But if OAuth uses parts of JavaScript API (such as XMLHttpRequest) that aren't available to Firefox Addons, then it isn't possible without modifying the module.

Comment: @WeirdestQuestions if `browserify` fails on the module, then you cannot use it in a firefox addon. Browserify faisl when the node module uses things like C and other native code. XMLHttpRequest and all other web features are available to firefox addons. You will have to tweak the way you get an instance of it though.

Answer (score 1):

You can but you have to [browserify](https://discourse.mozilla-community.org/t/browserify-to-use-npm-modules-in-an-addon/6970) and polyfill everything. And there is no documentation. You should browse some github repos to see how others devs are doing it.

On NPM, there are few modules designed for Firefox addons, they are tagged [*jetpack*](https://www.npmjs.com/browse/keyword/jetpack). There is one for [Google OAuth](https://www.npmjs.com/package/addon-google-oauth2), it may help if you need to write your own module.

Answer (score 1):

Fully working Twitter OAuth sign in, using JPM addon sdk:

https://github.com/Noitidart/jpmOAuth/

The dependencies that were needed were the CryptoJS files for the SHA1-HAMC encryption.

Install that addon. It will work perfectly.

When customizing for yourself, you will have to update the global variable `gOauth.twitter` entries of `callback`, `key`, and `secret`. You get this from the manage app on twitter:

The details page, this is where you get the `key` and `callback` - for me the url is - https://apps.twitter.com/app/12197899

[image]

Then from the "Keys and Access Tokens" page you get the `secret` - for me the url is - https://apps.twitter.com/app/12197899/keys

[image]